# pitfalls in sharing a conversational Hibernate EntityManager app-wide in read-only app?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-orm

We have a high-throughput read-only spring/jpa/hibernate app (web API) and found perf when relying on Hibernate's 2nd level cache to be unacceptable - essentially too much CPU time being spent re-hydrating entities within each read transaction on Session.get().

Thus, we're on path to cache (within VM) entities as objects (non de-hydrated) since:

- we can fit the entire datamodel within VM heap
- we don't care about stale-ness (can assume cache represents up-to-date state during app's lifetime)

Initially we thought to impl a write-through caching layer, which would sit between service and DAO layers.

However, **another approach** seems to be simpler given the above assumptions:

- declare a conversational EntityManager (init on app start, manually close on app stop):

  @PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED, properties =     {@PersistenceProperty(name = AvailableSettings.FLUSH_MODE,
              value = "MANUAL")})
  private HibernateEntityManager conversationalEM;
- inject the above proxy to all DAO impls
- (optional) pre-load all entities into EM at app startup in a separate transaction (to avoid possibility of multiple threads trying to write to the same Session subsequently)
- thus all operations like dao.loadEntity(id) would 'hit' shared Hibernate Session and return entity instance without DB query or re-hydration

**Any pitfalls with the latter approach?**

For example, EM will span many (always read-only) transactions, including concurrent (multiple clients hitting API concurrently), and those transactions will still have to be committed. Since Hibernate EM impl references tx object, seems like one could get into a situation wherein multiple threads are trying a commit() on the same TX object...